# A problem on Sylow Subgroups

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, sylow-theory

Let $|G| = 231$. Does there exist a Sylow $7$ subgroup that is normal in $G$?

Comment: Yes, if you want to know why, you will have to tell us what you know about the Sylow theorems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $231=3\times 7\times 11$, you get that $N_{7}=1$ where $N_7$ is the number of $7$-Sylow in $G$, using [Sylow's theorems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylow_theorems).

Since all $7$-Sylow are conjugate in $G$, the unique $7$-Sylow must be normal.